# Codeigniter - Sending a query result_arry() to a View for form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am using form_dropdown() and have a a problem below:

The form code is:

echo form_dropdown($level,$level_options,'1');

It works when I use

```
$level_options = array(
                  '1'  => 'Grade 6',
                  '2'    => 'Grade 7'
                );
```

but not when I send a $data['levels'] from controller to view

For reference, the model database retrieve code is:

```
public function getAllLevelNames() {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT level_description from levels ORDER BY level_description");
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

**The Problem**

The problem is I get a dropdown pick list with:

```
0

Grade 6

1

Grade 7
```

The indexes are greyed out.

How do I get rid of the indexes?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.

I seem to have the form working now with a data['levels'] sent to the view.  Now, the following code in my view seems to return "null" to my controller.  Any ideas why please?

```
$level = array(
              'name'        => 'level',
              'id'          => 'level',
              'value'       => '1',
              'maxlength'   => '50',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
            );


$level_options = $levels;

echo "<p>Level: ";
echo form_dropdown($level,$level_options,'1');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through your results_array and create a new array which is formatted correctly.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT level_description from levels ORDER BY level_description");

$for_dropdown = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $for_dropdown[$row->level_description] = $row->level_description;
}

return $for_dropdown;
```

Also I'm not sure how your `levels` table is structured, but usually you'll have an ID of some sort, which will be the primary key. If you do have that, you can include it in your query and have something like this instead:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, level_description from levels ORDER BY level_description");
... // other code
    $for_dropdown[$row->id] = $row->level_description;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I would love to send the ID as well and will try that to see if it will take.  Ideally, I could return from the dropdown with the ID as well but not sure how to execute that right now.

Comment: I am able to get the right values in the dropdown list but I have a new downstream problem...

The form_submit seems to send back "null".  Not sure why this is?

Comment: Do you know why my form_submit returns with null values?

I use: {$c_level = $this->input->post('course_level');} and in my form_validation and yet it comes back empty in the $c_level variable

Comment: I'd probably need to see more of the code to figure that out!

Comment: Try putting just the name as a string in the first parameter, and all your other options as the 4th one. The documentation doesn't mention supporting a 1st argument of an array like the form_input for example: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html